# How to create an image from a JFrame with setVisible(false)?

Tags: java, jframe, bufferedimage

I created a JFrame which basically creates a grid with some calculation, and I needed to get an image from that and I am currently using:

```
public static BufferedImage createImageFromFrame(Component component) {
    int w = component.getWidth();
    int h = component.getHeight();
    BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(w,h,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    component.paint( image.getGraphics() );
    return image;
}
```

calling like:

```
JFrame window = new JFrame();
// set stuff
BufferedImage img = d.createImageFromFrame(window.getContentPane());
```

And that do just fine. But now I want to create multiples images from different Frames, and I don't want to each one appear on the screen, I just want the images generated from them.
But I noticed I cannot use `setVisible(false)` cause it gives a `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Width (0) and height (0) cannot be <= 0`.

Is there any work around, or something to change that may help me accomplished that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pack the frame and move it outside of the visible area of your display. For example:

```
frame.pack();
frame.setLocation(-2000, -2000);
frame.setVisible(true);
// There you go, the frame won't be visible
```

Comment: hahah I don't know how I did not think of it. Simple enough, thank you very much (Will accept after 8 minutes)

Comment: Ok, but I didn't noticed, although it does not really display the frames, they are obviously still there visible at Alt-TAB, which does not look elegant. Is there any way to completely get rid of the frames and just get the images from them?

Comment: You can use a `JWindow` instead of the `JFrame`. `JWindow`s are not visible on the taskbar neither on the task list.

Comment: I do not need this for now, but next time I will try `JWindows`. Thank you very much @icza.